# How can I attach a shelf to a tile wall in a repairable manner?

Tags: tile, shelving, mounting

I am renting a flat and have permission from the landlord to put up shelves etc as long as "I don't wreck the place".

In the kitchen there is a lack of storage space, and a large blank tiled wall above the sink and worktop. I would like to make use of this space for storage using a couple of shallow shelves.

What is the best way to attach shelves to a tiled wall in a way that can be easily repaired with minimal noticeable damage?

The wall behind the tiles is brick, so will take screws very well. The tiles are ceramic, but not glazed, so will not take any kind of suction cup.

Comment: How much weight are we talking about?

Comment: As an alternative to drilling into the tile, you can look into ceiling mounted shelving.

Comment: I'm not looking to store much weight there, just coffee jars, soup tins, etc. Probably in the region of 5-10Kg per meter.

Comment: @Droid - I'm not sure what you mean by ceiling mounted shelving - can you link to an example? I'm not sure of the load bearing capacity of the ceiling material (don't know if it is solid plastered concrete or joists and plasterboard).

Answer (score 7):

Depending upon how large the grout lines are I would carefully drill through those with a masonry bit, and then use plastic anchors and fasten shelf brackets with screws. Use enough brackets to support the size shelf you need. Then, if the shelf ever needs to come down the holes in the grout lines can be repaired easily.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to mounting shelves on the wall is to simply bring in some shelving of the type pictured below. This type is available in various widths, lengths and heights. The shelves are adjustable through a large range so you can customize the installation to your needs.

[image]

Another good thing is that when you eventually move you can easily take the shelves with you!!

Comment: The wall in question is above a worktop unfortunately, so I don't have available floor space underneath.

Comment: You might be able to use a shelf like this on top of your counter. I used an ikea shelf similar to this on a countertop once. I was able to construct it without a bottom shelf so I could use the countertop surface, and I used the shelves above for a microwave and other storage. Totally removable since it's just sitting on the countertop.

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternatives:

- [Ceiling mounted shelving](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbcf9/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&storeId=10051)
- [Ceiling mounted baskets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000F7DT4C)
- [Corner shelving](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004EPXKJU) (held in place by pressure on floor or in your case the counter top and the ceiling)
- [Tension shower rods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PS8QTO) (not the same as shelving, and would only work if you have a cabinet on each side above your sink).